# How to retrieve Spring JPA entity by child property in unidirectional relationship?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Spring JPA find entity by child property in uni-directional relationship returns null despite data

inserting data into the database & restructuring the JPA query

I am trying to find a user by the property CurrentEmail which is from the credentials.

The credentials is a uni-directional relationship owned by user.

I do NOT want a bi-directional relationship as this will cause a lot of issues with updating & persisting changes to both instances

code:

user repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {
    Optional<User> findUserByCredentialsCurrentEmail(String email); // always return null
```

user:

```
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @Entity //needed for database mapping
@Table(name = "User") @Builder
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_notes",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "note_id"))
    private Set<Note> notes = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Credentials credentials;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private PersonalInformation personalInformation;

    @Column(name = "terms_and_conditions")
    private boolean termsAndConditions = false;

    @Column(name = "initial_register")
    private boolean initialRegister = false;

    private boolean hidden=false;

    private LocalDateTime creation;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    public LocalDateTime last_updated;

    @Version
    public Long version = 0L;
```

credentials:

```
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @Entity //needed for database mapping
@Table(name = "Credentials")
public class Credentials implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
  @Type(type = "uuid-char")
  private UUID id;
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String originalEmail;

  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String currentEmail;
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String password;

  @Column(nullable = true)
  public LocalDateTime lastUpdated;

  public Boolean expired = false;
  private boolean enabled=true;

  @Version
  public Long version = 0L;
```

Comment: Missing @Entity annotation in User class?

Comment: @Mar-Z my bad i didnt include it in the post, but this is not the problem with the code